# Include Quarters in Quarter Picker in React Date Picker by Hacker One

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, timestamp, react-datepicker

`Just like we have the include months in month picker in react date picker by hackerone, how can we include specific quarters?

Link of the date picker package : https://reactdatepicker.com/

If I enter something like this, it doesn't enable disable correct quarters.

includeDates={[
1661990400000, 1664582400000, 1667260800000, 1672531200000,
]}
Can you please help what I am missing here?

I tried to put timestamp in an array -> 1st day of each quarter, but it didnt work.

E.g. I want Q1, 2022 ; Q4, 2022; Q1, 2023 - enabled. Rest all disabled`